# How Can I access direct to a child node in order to update/remove?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have an xml file like this:

```
<participants>
  <participant>
    <number>1</number>
    <name>toto</name>
  </participant>
  <participant>
    <number>2</number>
    <name>titi</titi>
  </participant>
  <participant>
    <number>3</number>
    <name>tata</titi>
  </participant>
</participants>
```

I have a number of the participant and want to access direct to the node to update or delete it.

The problem is `$x` is not correct because of `echo $x->number` and `echo $x->name` is blank and the if is false.

```
    $x = $participant->item($number);

    echo 'number = '.$x->number;
    echo 'name = '.$x->name;
```

Any help please. Thanks.

```
$number=2;
if ($xml = file_get_contents($file)) 
{
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $xmldoc->loadXML($xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

    // find the participants tag
    $root = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('participants')->item(0);

    // get the list of participant node
    $participant = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('participant') ; 
    echo $participant->length; // I have a good number of participant node

            // get the node with the number i want
    $x = $participant->item($number);

    echo 'number = '.$x->number;
    echo 'name = '.$x->name;

    if ($x->number == $number) {
        echo "remove";
        $participant.removeChild($x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work for me .

```
<?php
$number=2;
if ($xml = file_get_contents("a.xml")) 
{
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $xmldoc->loadXML($xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

    // find the participants tag
    $root = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('participants')->item(0);

    // get the list of participant node
    $participant = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('participant'); 
    $participant->length; // I have a good number of participant node

            // get the node with the number i want
    $name_get = $participant->item($number-1)->getElementsByTagName('number')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $number_get = $participant->item($number-1)->getElementsByTagName('number')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo 'number = '.$name_get;
    echo 'name = '.$number_get;

    if ($number_get == $number) {
        echo "remove";
        $removing_node = $participant->item($number_get-1);
        $root->removeChild($removing_node);
    }
}
echo $xmldoc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly. But I don't understand the logic, what's wrong when i try to access $participant->item($number) (ok for the mistake $number-1) and after $x->number ?

Comment: item() function returns a DOMElement, and DOMElement has methods but not variables or elements .